# Join table when no result match

Tags: mysql, join

I'm struggling with this for hours with no success.
I created a table containing 24 hours called hours_table with column hours with 00->23 and column result all 0.
I've table with calls duration which I'm trying to group sum of calls duration per time of day.

```
SELECT  date_format(date, '%H' ) as todayhours ,truncate(sum(duration),2) 
as result FROM OutgoingCalls a 
where date > CURDATE() group by date_format(date, '%H' )
```

This statment provide:

```
Todayhours , result
00         ,  6
02         ,  5
04         ,  1
05         ,  2
06         ,  10
07         ,  10
08         , 162 `
```

I want to get the missing hours with 0 like:

```
Todayhours , result
00         ,  6
01         ,  0
02         ,  5
03         ,  0
04         ,  1
05         ,  2
06         ,  10
07         ,  10
08         , 162
```

The hours_table looks like:

```
hours       result
00          0
01          0
02          0
...
23          0
```

I've this SQL:

```
SELECT  date_format(date, '%H' ) as todayhours ,truncate(sum(duration),2) 
as result FROM OutgoingCalls a
LEFT JOIN hours_table h ON h.hours = date_format(date, '%H' )
where date > CURDATE() group by h.hours
```

No matter changes I made from right to left join I only getting the hours found from the OutgoingCalls select (first one without the join).

I'm looking to get all 24 hours when the result from the OutgoingCalls have no result in certain hour.

Comment: Please add the table structure of both tables. You may be comparing apples to oranges. Also, please add sample data; a few rows will go a long way to help us reproduce the case.

Comment: Edit my question with some additional data

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Details matter. Also cutting & pasting.

Answer (score 0):

You should flip the outer join. The main table should be `hours_table` instead of `OutgoingCalls`, as in:

```
SELECT
  h.hours,
  date_format(date, '%H' ) as todayhours,
  truncate(sum(duration),2) as result
FROM hours_table h
LEFT JOIN OutgoingCalls a ON h.hours = date_format(date, '%H' )
WHERE date > CURDATE()
GROUP BY h.hours
```

Comment: Thanks but I still get the same result as stated from my own above SQL. No matter what I'm doing it's still skipping the missing hours.

Comment: If the main table "hours_table" has 24 rows, then this query will show you 24 rows. Are you sure it does have all 24 rows?

Comment: it may be the format of the data in the hours lookup table that is not matching... @Sam, please confirm the table structure format of HOURS_TABLE is expected STRING format to match leading 01, 02, 03, etc hour format vs just 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @DRapp Yeah, I was thinking about that, but in my query the aggregation is performed with data from the `hours_table` uniquely. It should always have the number of rows that table has. I don't know about the OP's query, though.

Comment: Correct, hence the OPs format of 01, 02, 03 vs his hourly table having numeric 1, 2, 3.  If it does not match based on conversion to CHARACTER,  "01" will not match "1" and thus have null matches... There would be if 10, 11, 12 since those would be 2 digits, but we are not that far into the year yet to get those... @Sam, please read and confirm above context of hour HOURS_TABLE structure to match.

Comment: The first thing I changed is the hours_table from INT 0->23 to CHAR 00->23. This table result shown above as 00,01,02 exactly as the result of the date_format result. I thought it can be type mismatch and I also tried converted the output of the date_format. The date_format extract the hours from date type and the hours_table is in a different format but with the same expected values.